# Facebook permission review completed without verdict

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-permissions

I had given my android-application for '**user_friends**' permission review.

Today I got an alert that *my application review has been completed*.
[image]

When I go to '**Go to App Review**' page it does not show '**Permission Rejected**' Or '**Permission Approved**'.
[image]

It is not available in '**Approved Items**' list either!
[image]

**My question** : How would I know that my requested permission(user_friends) access has been granted or not!?

Comment: If it was granted, then it should show up under Approved Items. Suggest you use the ask a question button to clear this up with Facebook directly.

Comment: They do not reply that frequently, I had asked one question month ago, which has not been answered yet!

Comment: If you start a new submission, does it allow you to add that same item again then?

Comment: Yes, It does allow...

Comment: Well then I wouldn’t know what else to advise other than that you submit it again. If you say support questions aren’t answered in a timely manner, then I don’t think there is any faster way.

Comment: Yaa right, @CBroe Thank you...